# xcode spell checking

Tags: xcode, spell-checking

Is there a way to enable spell checking in xcode (maybe and add-on) that does spell checking only inside comments and not in code? (like vim/emacs spell checker).

I have tried what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697044/xcode-spell-checking) but it seems check the entire document since it complains about some variable names and macros (which I obviously don't want to spell check).

Comment: a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2697044/1151916

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 4 also includes a new Fix-It feature, which is basically a spell-checker for code. It highlights your mistakes, and with the press of the "Fix" button, the problem is solved.

It just shows you a red circle on the line number that you have to click to get the fix it suggestions. You can use a keyboard shortcut to do the fixing at least. Here is the "Fix all in scope" key bind.

```
Fix Next Issue:
control + Command + '

Fix Previous Issue:
control + Command + "

Fix All In Scope:
control + Command + F
```

The closest thing I've been seen that shows errors as you type is to switch to issue navigator and leave that on.
Here is a guide on the issue navigator. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-issue_navigator/articles/viewing_issues_in_the_issue_navigator.html Hope this helped.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the question?

Comment: Oh that missed my eye... I'll change my answer