# Enable Xcode's "Check Spelling While Typing" Option by Default

Tags: xcode, spell-checking

Is there any way to enable Xcode's ***Check Spelling While Typing*** option on every Xcode project and file by default?

Currently, I have to set this option on each file, and the option gets reset after closing Xcode.

Option in question (Edit>Format>Spelling and Grammar>Check Spelling While Typing):

[image: Xcode's Check Spelling While Typing Option]

Comment: Lots of really poor answers here.  I've been digging through Xcode's prefs trying to find this...

Comment: Find it really strange that it does not persist. Even when switching files it looses the setting. Guess the best way is to set a easy hotkey in the Xcode Key Bindings preferences say **Opt+Cmd+;** and then press it. Its too hard to go so many menu levels to enable it every time.

Comment: Certainly, you may make a case for a preference option, but maybe Apple thinks spell check within a code editor is so rare that it resets off.  Between Issues Editor and code completion, Xcode is checking against previously defined reserved words.  Spell check would flag every non-trivial variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode's Check Spelling While Typing setting persists in Xcode 11 and above. The scope of the setting is Xcode and not a project.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change the default setting in *System Preferences*, then *Language & Region* and in *Keyboard Preferences* (Text tab) you can enable/disable ***Correct spelling automatically*** option.

[image: Mac, System Preferences, Language & Region, Keyboard Preferences, screenshot of window]

Tested under *OS X - El Capitan*.

See also: [Turn off Spell Checking permanently](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2577594)

Answer (score -5):

While I don't know a way to do this automatically, you can make choosing this option a little faster by setting up a shortcut in Sys Prefs->Keyboard->Shortcuts. Click App Shortcuts then the Plus button to add a keyboard shortcut that triggers this menu item.