# xcode 9 spell check greyed out

Tags: xcode9

Since I updated to xcode9 I am unable to use the spell checker function. E.g. Going to Edit > Format > Spelling & Grammar has all spell checker options graded out apart from "Show Spelling and Grammar".

Clicking on Show Spelling and Grammar brings up spell checker box but it does not search the page, even when you press next.

I like to use spellchecker to check my comments and string literals. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri7TA.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode spell checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697044/xcode-spell-checking)

Comment: Fixed in Xcode 11.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate post but I'll answer anyway.

This is an Xcode bug. There have been radars filed. As far as I am unaware there is no work around or fix  currently.